# Should I recompile .po files to .mo on the server in deployment, or deploy .mo?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext

I have a `.po` file containing translations for my app, and used `django-admin compilemessages` to create `.mo` files locally which work fine.

In deployment, should I recompile `po` to `mo` on the server (Elastic Beanstalk), or just track the compiled `mo` files in version control and upload them? [This `.gitignore` template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) has `.mo` files ignored which would suggest they should be compiled on the server, but I'm not sure why. Are the compiled files specific to each server somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.po` and `.mo` files should be created in your local machine and be versioned in vcs (version control system). and once they are uploaded, you dont need to recompile, just restart your app and new strings should be working. so:

```
# local dev machine
python manage.py makemessages 
python manage.py compilemessages

# deploy
eb deploy
```

`eb deploy` should restart your django app automatically (I have no experience with eb)